# Can a program that controls IE detect if a HTTP 30x code is encountered?

Tags: internet-explorer, com, automation, ole

I am trying to control an `InternetExplorer.Application` via the COM interface, using Perl, `Win32::OLE`, and information from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084%28VS.85%29.aspx). My goal is to get as good an idea as possible about what IE is doing. (Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329706/internet-explorer-com-automation-converting-numeric-error-code-to-string) question.)

IE uses events to notify my program when it has finished various stages of processing a certain URL (`NavigateComplete2`, `DownloadComplete` `DocumentComplete`). It can also tell my program about various errors it encounters (`NavigateError2`). I consider that part of my problem solved well enough.

I would also like to be able to reliably detect if IE is redirected by the server. Primarily, I'm concerned about HTTP 30x status codes. Is there a way to do this, either with COM automation or via another route?

Answer (score 1):

**Hi Hillu.**

I use [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net) to *bend* Internet Explorer to the will of my applications.

I don't think you can use Perl with it. But any way it might help.

Its a nice .NET library with almost 5 years, its devoted to the automation of Internet Explorer, first developed to speed up testing of Web Applications.

Some of its features:

- Automates all major HTML elements
- Find elements by multiple attributes
- Supports AJAX website testing
- Supports frames (cross domain) and iframes
- Supports popup dialogs like alert, confirm, login etc..
- Supports HTML dialogs (modal and modeless)
- Provides a Page and Control model.
- Supports creating screenshots of webpages
- Has a basic (extensible) logging mechanism
- Easy to integrate with your favorit (unit) test tool
- Works with Internet Explorer 6, 7, 8 and FireFox 2 and 3

I'm sure if you have a look around its [documentation](http:///watin.sourceforge.net/doc) you will find something of use in helping you with your problem, and if not i think this blog [post](http://watinandmore.blogspot.com/2008/04/catching-server-errors-with-watin.html) will give you a simple way of checking if IE as turned a server error page.

Hope it helps. Fábio